# No call of constructor of singleton

Tags: c++, c++11, assembly

I have singleton class, intended to for use in one thread (GUI thread),
to protected from wrong usage I add `assert`

```
//header file
class ImageCache final {
public:
    ImageCache(const ImageCache &) = delete;
    ImageCache &operator=(const ImageCache &) = delete;
    static ImageCache &instance()
    {
       static ImageCache cache;
       return cache;
    }
    void f();
private:
    QThread *create_context_ = nullptr;
    ImageCache();
};

//cpp
ImageCache::ImageCache()
{
    create_context_ = QThread::currentThread();
    qInfo("begin, cur thread %p\n", create_context_);
}

void ImageCache::f()
{
    assert(create_context_ == QThread::currentThread());
}
```

all works fine, but on one machine there is assertion failure in `ImageCache::f`,
I **have no direct access to that machine** (hence this question).

The interesting thing, that according to log `ImageCache::ImageCache`
was not called at all, and assert failed because of

`assert(0 == QThread::currentThread());`

I move implementation of `ImageCache::instance` from header file to `.cpp` file,
send updated source code to user of these machine (on my all works fine),
he rebuilds and all start works as expected.

I ask him for compiled binaries (with assert failure and without) the only difference between them is place of `ImageCache::instance` implementation,

and compare assembler.

there is no difference between calls of `ImageInstance::instance().f()`
at all,
and there is one difference in disassembler of `ImageInstance::instance`,

the failure one looks like this:

```
 static ImageCache &instance()
   4938f:   55                      push   %rbp
   49390:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   49393:   41 54                   push   %r12
   49395:   53                      push   %rbx
    {
        static ImageCache cache;
   49396:   48 8b 05 bb db 23 00    mov    0x23dbbb(%rip),%rax        # 286f58 <_ZGVZN10ImageCache8instanceEvE5cache@@Base-0x2150>
   4939d:   0f b6 00                movzbl (%rax),%eax
   493a0:   84 c0                   test   %al,%al
   493a2:   0f 94 c0                sete   %al
   493a5:   84 c0                   test   %al,%al
   493a7:   74 5c                   je     49405 <_ZN10ImageCache8instanceEv+0x76>
   493a9:   48 8b 05 a8 db 23 00    mov    0x23dba8(%rip),%rax        # 286f58 <_ZGVZN10ImageCache8instanceEvE5cache@@Base-0x2150>
   493b0:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
   493b3:   e8 08 b7 fe ff          callq  34ac0 <__cxa_guard_acquire@plt>
```

the good one is looks like  this:

```
ImageCache &ImageCache::instance()
{
   50c12:   55                      push   %rbp
   50c13:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   50c16:   41 54                   push   %r12
   50c18:   53                      push   %rbx
    static ImageCache cache;
   50c19:   0f b6 05 98 94 23 00    movzbl 0x239498(%rip),%eax        # 28a0b8 <_ZGVZN10ImageCache8instanceEvE5cache>
   50c20:   84 c0                   test   %al,%al
   50c22:   0f 94 c0                sete   %al
   50c25:   84 c0                   test   %al,%al
   50c27:   74 50                   je     50c79 <_ZN10ImageCache8instanceEv+0x67>
   50c29:   48 8d 3d 88 94 23 00    lea    0x239488(%rip),%rdi        # 28a0b8 <_ZGVZN10ImageCache8instanceEvE5cache>
   50c30:   e8 cb 3d fe ff          callq  34a00 <__cxa_guard_acquire@plt>
```

The difference is

```
//bad
mov    0x23dbbb(%rip),%rax 
movzbl (%rax),%eax
//good
movzbl 0x239498(%rip),%eax
```

I interpret this, that for some reason `%eax` register from the first one variant got wrong value, and because of this got decision that global object was initialized while it is not initialized. In the second case all works as expected.

So is it compiler failure (`gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0 / amd64 / linux`) or I should use ImageCache::instance inside `.cpp` for some reason,
or some other reason that cause difference code generation, like some compiler falgs may cause this failure? Code was compiled with `-O0 -std=c++11` and some other flags that cmake add automatically while compile shared library with dependency on Qt library.

Also I ask test code with usage of `fprintf(stderr` instead of `qInfo`,
and the user see output in the second case and no output in the first case.

Comment: I assume you don't see logs for `ImageCache::ImageCache` because it is statically built, probably before the logger was initialized. 

I suggest you construct the Singleton in a "lazy" manner (hold a static pointer data-member to it which is initialized to null, and construct an instance the first time `ImageCache::instance()` is called and the pointer is null. Consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).

Comment: @uv_ Not sure that undernstand you, in both cases compiler generate code that create `static ImageCache instance;` in "lazy" manner, see call of `cxa_guard_acquire` in both cases.

Comment: @uv_ and see note that available by your reference: `C++11 For the singleton pattern, double-checked locking is not needed: ` , I use `c++11`.

Comment: Right now, `instance` is a static instance, which is constructed in static-time. My suggestion is to hold `static ImageCache* instance = null`, and initialize it (`new`) upon the first call of `ImageCache::instance()`.

Comment: @uv_ As I know at least for C++11 case you are not right. The first call cause construction of object. This is trick to handle `c++` problem with unspecificied order of static object intializaton.

Comment: You should compare the version of the compiler on both machines as it might be a bug. Also, you might need to check how the singleton is used on user machine (assuming that user application is not the same one as you). Also compiling the same test application on both machines and then executing both versions on both computer should help to get a good picture of the problem.

Comment: I'd be curious to see the `g++ -O3 -S -fverbose-asm` output from the "bad" version.  (Or `-O0` I guess, if that's what you've been using.  `-O0` somewhat explains the braindead test/sete/test).  Anyway. having symbolic names like `foo@gotpcrel(%rip)` might shed some light on why we have an extra level of indirection in the "bad" version (loading a pointer from static data and then dereferencing it to zero-extend a byte, vs. directly addressing a byte of static data in the "good" version.)

Comment: Can you include a [mcve] that reproduces the problem on the machine where your code breaks?  The snippet you show doesn't compile on its own on the Godbolt compiler explorer (which has various gcc versions from 4.x through 8.2).  https://godbolt.org/z/kXtJvG  I don't think it has Qt headers available at all, but it's a handy way to look for asm output differences.  (The asm diff you show might be from compiling with a default of `-pie` vs. `-no-pie`.  Recent Ubuntu defaults to PIE)

Comment: The inline `instance` function has to handle the static variable, and the associated boolean flag indicating that it has been initialized, differently than the non-inline version.  Since every Translation Unit will initially have its own copy of the function and variables, the generated code accesses the one copy that will be shared thru a pointer, rather than directly.  This is what the two "bad" instructions are doing.  But that doesn't explain the assertion failure.

Comment: `static` variables in inline function were "bugged" with older compilers. See the documentation for gcc -fno-gnu-unique.

Answer (score 1):

**Original answer**

As far as I understand, the problem having the function in the header file is that you can get multiple definitions and then the behavior is unspecified.

Essentially, the compiler might generate multiple functions `instance`, one for each compilation unit that include that header and as such if they are not merge/eliminated at link time, each one would have their own variable.

In windows, we can have similar problem if we compile the same code in multiple DLLs where some variables get duplicated in each dynamic library.

Then what would happen is that because each client has their own copy, a change made by one is not seen by another client in another translation unit (your problem) or another DLL (my problem).

By moving the definition to the source file, you will get a single definition and thus avoid the problem.

In C++, if you don't follow the specification, you often get undefined behavior. It is up to the programmer to know what he is doing.

**Update**

As pointed out, in a comment my assumption might be wrong according to current standard. Thus the problem might also be an **outdated compiler** or a **compiler bug**.

Possible explanation of what is happening:

In many cases, when the compiler merge duplicates, the code would be identical so it would not make any difference which one is selected. Here, assuming that the compiler assign 2 different addresses for the static variable (one for each compilation unit) and somehow inline the call to `instance()` in a way that it used the original variable instead of the merged (selected) one, it might explain the observed behavior.

Comment: C++ does guarantee that a function-static variable is unique, even if the function is inline and its definition is in multiple translation units. Though I'm not certain if Windows DLL linking will be able to correctly honor that rule in all cases.

Comment: @aschepler I have added some precision that it might be a compiler bug… In the past, one has to declare class static variables inside CPP file (except for template) so it is possible that a compiler was not properly handling that edge case.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with `QThread::currentThread()`. It is using a module local static object - I guess. And if that is the case, the link order of the module with user code results in behavioral difference. Have you tried a different version of QT?
I guess this version of Qt has an outdated design - not using modern idioms such as Meyer singleton or even the old nifty counter trick.